# desaturate an OpenGL texture

Tags: c#, opengl, colors, grayscale, opentk

I have a .png with **transparency** that I need to desaturate. I read I need to take the average R,G and B value of the bitmap then use:

```
G*.59
R*.3
B*.11
```

I calculate the average color in this way:

```
private Color Average_Color(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Color c = new Color();
  int pixel_number = 0;
  int r = 0;
  int g = 0;
  int b = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; j++) {
      c = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
        r += c.R;
        g += c.G;
        b += c.B;
        pixel_number++;
    }
  }
  c = Color.FromArgb(1, r / pixel_number, g / pixel_number, b / pixel_number);
  return c;
}
```

Then, first to paint my texture, I set the Color in this way:

```
rgb = Average(bitmap);
GL.Color3(rgb.R * 0.59, rgb.G * 0.3, rgb.B * 0.11);
//here I draw my texture
```

I don't know why but it doesn't work (I get the texture with his original colors). I guess it's something wrong in `Average_Color`. Maybe because it's not a total opaque bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL expects its colors to be floats normalized from 0 to 1, but I suspect that your bitmap is reporting colors from 0-255.

Therefore I assume you're passing RGB values much greater than 1 to glColor, which get clamped to 1, so your texture looks the same.

Try

`GL.Color3(rgb.R*0.59/255.f, rgb.G*0.3/255.f, rgb.B*0.11/255.f);`

Comment: you are right, done in this way but it's not grayscaled, it's dark-red.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You're removing more green and blue from the image than red, so it looks red. Why should it come out grayscale? @FrankLioty

Comment: so what I have to do to desature my texture? @Tim

Comment: You need to average all three colors using the weighted averages like you did, then combine them together to get a single grey value, and pass that value to all three colors. E.g.:

`float colorVal = ((r * 0.59f + g * 0.3f + b * 0.11f) / 3.0f);`
`glColor4f(colorVal, colorVal, colorVal, alpha);`

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your variables to floats before the divide